# Synchronizing UI thread with dispatched View states dependant on worker thread events?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-testing, ui-thread

There is an Activity and a button on it. The task is to pass white-box test for an influence of Activity consequence behaviour "Button CLICK -> Button GONE -> Activity PAUSE -> Activity RESUME" on button visability state.

Naive implementation leads to inconsistent Activity state and consequently wrong test outputs:

```
// worker thread
TouchUtils.clickView(this, mButton);
...
// ui thread
instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(mActivity);
instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(mActivity);
assertTrue(View.GONE == mButton.getVisibility());
```

Two glympse approaches don't successed:

1) Adding sleep for main thread after `TouchUtils.clickView()` execution however doesn't solve problem completely but creates additional dependancy on empirical UI timeout duration.

2) Synchronizing touch events and consequent Activity lifecycle events invocation via `onPostExecute()` from **AsyncTask** causes tests to fail unpredictably.

Is there any canonical or at least viable solution for worker-ui synchronization at general or specially designed for Android Test framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to use `runOnMainSync()` from  **Instrumentation.class** for synchronizing UI and worker threads events via Android Test Framework instrumentation:

```
// worker thread
TouchUtils.clickView(this, mButton);
instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(mActivity);
        instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(mActivity);
        assertTrue(View.GONE == mButton.getVisibility());
    }
});
```

However if there are any other suggestions or general (not Android Test Framework related) guidelines answers are appreciated.

**Note:** more special  tools for synchronization with main thread are described in the official [best practices for testing](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/activity-testing/activity-functional-testing.html#keyinput).